# Reading a portion of the ajax html response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My ajax (jquery) response (html) gives me a whole junk of html source code since it fetches the enrite page.

The response is somewhat like below:

```
<html>
<head>
...
...
</head>
<body>
.
.....
.

.......

<div id="content">
    content i want to extract
</div>
.............
..........
.............

</body>
</html>
```

I need help with the following:

1) Is it possible to read just whatever is between the `<div id='content'></div>`? if yes, how?

2) if #1 is not possible, how could I extract just the content from the `<div id='content'></div>`?

The code I tried:

```
    /*Ajax*/
    $jq(function(){
    alert ("Doc ready");
        $jq("#content a.next-page").bind("click", function(e){
            alert ("Hey!");
            /*Make the call*/
            $jq.ajax({
                url: "/page/2",
                type: "get",
                cache: false,
                data: "",
                error: function(){alert ("No data found for your search.");},
                success: function(results){
                    //$searchPanel.find("tbody").empty().append(results);
                    //$searchPanelHolder.css({"display":"block"});
                    alert (results.find("div[id='content']").html());
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Any help on this is much appreciated

Many thanks,
Racky

Comment: Justa  general comment; since you're fetching an html page directly without passing through a backend "bridge" I assume the page is on your own domain, the same one where your script is coming from. In this case, you should spend the time to develop a PHP (or whatever) script that taps directly into your database and returns the data you're interested in in JSON or XML format. This way your JS snippet will work even if you change the markup of that page.

Comment: You should check someone's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to make a jQuery object out of it first.

Change this line:

```
alert (results.find("div[id='content']").html());
```

to this:

```
alert ( $(results).find("div[id='content']").html() );
```

or, better yet, to this:

```
alert ( $(results).find("#content").html() );
```

---

**EDIT:**

Looks like if the element you want is a direct child of `body`, you'll need to use `.filter()` instead since the `body` seems to be excluded from the jQuery object. Looks like just its contents are included.

```
alert ( $(results).filter("#content").html() );
```

Comment: @racky - You're welcome. :o) FYI, using `.find()` is a *tiny* bit faster than `$("#content", results)` since jQuery just converts that into `.find()` anyway. Won't be a noticeable difference, though.

Comment: hey thanks again, another tiny issue, now i get the required data with your kind help. what I am now doing is empty the old content from the div [$("#content").empty()] and append the newly retrieved data [.append(newdata)]. But this one strangely reloads the page to a blank page! any thoughts around this?

Comment: @racky - Not sure why that would happen. Could you please update your question adding the relevant code at the bottom. Don't change the existing question, otherwise it may confuse things.

Comment: @Patrick: The only change is in the success segment of the ajax request:
<pre><code>
success: function(results){
     var $f = $jq(results).find("#content").html();
     //alert ($f);
     $jq("#content").empty().append($f);    }
</code></pre>

Comment: @racky - I assume your alert is showing you the expected data. Your code should work. Check for invalid HTML markup either in the original page, or in the response received. Also, how is the AJAX being triggered? Clicking a link? Submitting a form?

Comment: yes. the alert is showing the expected data. I am checking for invalid html. Since the output is huge, I'm not sure i can finish dong that. The ajax is triggered on clicking on a link.

Comment: @Patrick, i have tried return false but no luck. something really strange... thanks for the help.... let me know if you have any new ideas:) thanks a lot :)

Comment: @racky - Instead of appending the data you receive, try appending something simple, like `<div>test content</div>` and see if that works properly. If it does, then it is most likely some markup issue in the data. I believe there are HTML validators available online that will tell you if your markup is valid.

Comment: @patrick, there was problem with the markup and I am fixing it... hopefully that should solve my problem. I really appreciate your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
$("#content", results).html()
```